# Error building cf-cli: go build runtime: linux/386 must be bootstrapped using make.bash

Tags: linux, go, cross-compiling, cloud-foundry

The CLI tool for Cloud Foundry available at [cloudfoundry/cli](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli) is written in Go. I'm trying to build the CLI tool but getting this error:

**go build runtime: linux/386 must be bootstrapped using make.bash**

How to solve this problem?

Here are the contents of the `cli/bin/build-all.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

OUTDIR=$(dirname $0)/../out

GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=windows $(dirname $0)/build && cp $OUTDIR/cf $OUTDIR/cf-windows-amd64.exe
GOARCH=386 GOOS=windows $(dirname $0)/build && cp $OUTDIR/cf $OUTDIR/cf-windows-386.exe
GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux $(dirname $0)/build  && cp $OUTDIR/cf $OUTDIR/cf-linux-amd64
GOARCH=386 GOOS=linux $(dirname $0)/build  && cp $OUTDIR/cf $OUTDIR/cf-linux-386
GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=darwin $(dirname $0)/build  && cp $OUTDIR/cf $OUTDIR/cf-darwin-amd64
```

Everything works fine and gets cross compiled except for the line `GOARCH=386 GOOS=linux`, which produces this error:

**go build runtime: linux/386 must be bootstrapped using make.bash**

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 and my go version is go1.3.3

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to the latest golang version and filing a bug if it continues to not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have golang-go-linux-386 installed.

```
sudo apt-get install golang-go-linux-386
```